# Friends network unreachable

Tags: steam

On steam, I cannot reach friend servers. This has been an issue for a month and does not happen on my other computer.
Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

I have tried resetting my steam, I have tried resetting my router, I have tried restarting my computer and none of these things have worked.

[image]

Comment: You need to put more information into the question for anyone to even have the chance to answer it -- stuff like system specs, what you've tried, what your network configuration is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall on your ... Mac? Linux?

[Steam Firewall Settings](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711)